# Location of Substrings within strings and their extentions

Tags: python, substring

this is a python noob posting here so plz dont be too harsh

I am tying to create a list of strings that are taken from a larger string which has multiple copys of the substring which in contains a relevent phrase such as the extention of a picture file like a .jpg

I have a programe that returns a list of the search phrase but the obvious problem with that is that i will get a list of identical phrases without the rest of the information. ie the name part of a name.jpg

If i was able to gather the position of phrase in each instance i should be able to add a cetain amount of characters before the phrase to the string to give names to the phrases. of course i wouldnt know how many characters to add infront of the string either but if it was something like /images/name.jpg then all i would need to do is find the end position of the /images part and add what ever is inbetween.

but i dont know how to find locations of substrings inside strings and i havnt been able to work out how to do this by looking through google or the python documentation

if anyone knows how to do this or if there is another way to go about what i want to do that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post with an example of the string you are starting with, and the list of strings you would like to extact?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a list of all the filenames which end in `.jpg` you could use a regular expression something like the following:

```
import re
jpglist = re.findall(r"[\w-]+\.jpg", string)
```

Here `[\w-]` will permit file names with alphanumeric, underscore and hyphen characters, but you can expand on that if needed.  Check out the `re` docs under string services in the std lib docs.